# Why use Adapter design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

So I am looking at the Adapter design pattern. I see that the intention is to allow a client to access the methods of a class where **their interfaces are incompatible**.

Now I have been looking at [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774259/Adapter-Design-Pattern-Csharp).

```
interface ITarget
{
  List<string> GetProducts();
}


public class VendorAdaptee
{
   public List<string> GetListOfProducts()
   {
      List<string> products = new List<string>();
      products.Add("Gaming Consoles");
      products.Add("Television");
      products.Add("Books");
      products.Add("Musical Instruments");
      return products;
   }
}

class VendorAdapter:ITarget
{
   public List<string> GetProducts()
   {
      VendorAdaptee adaptee = new VendorAdaptee();
      return adaptee.GetListOfProducts();
   }
}

class ShoppingPortalClient
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      ITarget adapter = new  VendorAdapter();
      foreach (string product in adapter.GetProducts())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(product);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

So based on the description **ShoppingPortalClient** wants to use **VendorAdaptee** but can't due to incompatible interface. Here is my stupid question...why can't ShoppingPortalClient just do this:

```
var adaptee = new VendorAdaptee();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the need of Adapter Design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188801/what-is-the-need-of-adapter-design-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShoppingPortalClient` cannot directly use the adaptee because the adaptee's interface is not an `ITarget` (which it expects). In other words, `VendorAdaptee` *does not* have a `GetProducts()` method, it has a `GetListOfProducts()` method. These are different interfaces. This will not work with the existing inventory management system which `ShoppingPortalClient` uses.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am not so sure I can agree with that because, I believe ITarget is created as part of the whole adapter design pattern. So if you only had the **Main** and the **VendorAdaptee**, why can't we just new VendoreAdaptee.

Comment: No, that's not correct. ITarget exists because the client depends on it, not because the adapter needs it. The adapter needs it only because the client needs it, which is the whole point of using the adapter and why this pattern exists in the first place.

Comment: The client expects one interface. The adaptee has a totally different interface. The adapter connects the two. The author of the article you posted even types the adapter **in Main** as `ITarget adapter `.

Comment: From the article *you* posted: "ITarget: This is the interface which is *used by the client* to achieve functionality."

Comment: Thanks Reafael. Yes, after your comment I re-read that and now it makes sense. So the ITarget is what the client depends on as you mentioned. Thanks. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The example doesn't really make sense.  There is no reason to use an adapter in `ShoppingPortalClient`, because that class has no requirement to use the `ITarget` interface.

If it had to pass an `ITarget` somewhere, e.g., if it had to call `performSomeOperation(ITarget)` in a different class, *then* it would make sense to create an adapter to pass in.